# Multidimensional array foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as shown below that I am wanting to simply get the value of [caption] which is in the [image_meta] array at the bottom.

```
Array
(
[file] => 2014/01/dreamstimecomp_5449062.jpg
[sizes] => Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => Array
            (
                [file] => dreamstimecomp_5449062-150x150.jpg
            )

        [medium] => Array
            (
                [file] => dreamstimecomp_5449062-300x224.jpg
            )

    )

[image_meta] => Array
    (
        [aperture] => 0
        [credit] => 
        [camera] => 
        [caption] => 
        [created_timestamp] => 0
        [copyright] => 
        [focal_length] => 0
        [iso] => 0
        [shutter_speed] => 0
        [title] => 
    )
```

)

I've tried this for each loop below but not working

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($caption_data); 
echo '</pre>';
foreach ($caption_data as $x=>$x_value){
    echo $x[0][3];
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($x);` And use `var_dump` every time you have no idea what's in a variable

Answer (score 1):

`echo $caption_data['image_meta']['caption']`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to get a single value. You can do:

```
$value = $array_containing_datastructure['image_meta']['caption'];
```